# My if variable is not triggering

Tags: python

I am trying to make a quiz using python which reads questions from a text file. I have a variable called `ans` which is supposed to be the answer which it reads from the file I print the variable and it says what its supposed to say but if I actually type it in it will say its wrong.
This is my python code:

```
right = 0
wrong = 0
num = 0
quest = 0
history = open("history.txt", "r")
lines = history.readlines()
while quest != 3:
    quest = quest+1
    num = num+1
    print("Question", quest)
    question = lines[num]
    print(question)
    num = num + 1
    ans = lines[num]
    print(ans)
    answer = input()
    answer = answer.lower()
    if answer == ans:
        print("correct")
        right = right+1
    else:
        print("Wrong")
        wrong = wrong+0
print("done")
```

And my history.txt file is formatted like this

```
Blank Line Blank Line
What is the capital of England?
london
What is 1+1?
2
```

Thank you.

Comment: `print(repr(ans),"=?=",repr(answer))` im sure you will quickly see your issue ...

Comment: You need to remove the newline from the user input (or the lines in the file). In many languages that's done with `chomp`. I don't know how to do it in Python, or whether `.readlines` or `input()` do it for you, but that's probably the problem. You can easily try by printing both strings including enclosing characters to see if the final character ends up in a new line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The strings returned by `history.readlines()` have newlines at the end of them, but the string returned by `input()` doesn't. Use `rstrip()` to remove any trailing whitespace from the string.

```
ans = lines[num].rstrip()
```

Answer (score 0):

`readlines()` leaves a newline (`\n`) character when it splits your string. Try setting `ans` with

```
ans = lines[num].rstrip()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try stepping through your program. If you print out the contents of lines after reading from the file, you'll see it has new line chars:

```
>>> history = open("history.txt", "r")
>>> lines = history.readlines()
>>> lines
['Blank Line Blank Line\n', 'What is the capital of England?\n', 'london\n', 'What is 1+1?\n', '2']
```

You'll need to trim the newline character
`ans = ans.rstrip("\n")`

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure there is a "new line char" - a.k.a '\n' - when you read from the file.
Take a look at this:

```
a = "123"
b = "123\n"
print(a == b)
Output: False
```

But:

```
a = "123"
b = "123\n"
print(a == b.rstrip())
True
```

Answer (score -1):

Due to the allready mentioned fact the a `\n` remains at the end of each line, I recommend using `re.split('\n',yourFile)` for splitting a string to its lines. The newline character often is not useful in such cases.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Well, I think it's a useful alternative solution to the given problem... and I think the better one, nevermind

Comment: It likely won't work if the file contains carriage returns as well as newline characters